# Changing the color of text in a table when hovering over it

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, onhover

I need the color of text in table to change when I hover over it. For this I use:

```
$('.afishaitem_active').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css({'border':'solid 1px #ED5353','background-color':'#FFF','color':'#ED5353'});
        $('.afishaitem_up_left_active').css('color','#000'); 
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css({'border':'none','background-color':'#ED5353','color':'#FFF'});
        $('.afishaitem_up_left_active').css('color','#000');
    }
);
```

and table:

```
<table id="afishaitem_active" class="afishaitem_active" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="afishaitem_up">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td class="afishaitem_up_left_active">'.$d.'</td>
                    <td class="afishaitem_up_right_active">data</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" style="line-height:11px">
        <td class="afishaitem_seet_active">seet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td class="afishaitem_name_active">name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When hovering over the table the border style and background-color change, but the text color does not.

Why does the color of the text not change?

Answer (score 0):

You put `'color','#000'` for both mouse over and mouse out, change the mouse over (first function) to the colour you want it to change to on hover.

Comment: not work change color in code:$(this).css({'border':'solid 1px #ED5353','background-color':'#FFF','color':'#ED5353'}

$(this).css({'border':'none','background-color':'#ED5353','color':'#FFF'});[/code]

not work change [code]'color':'#ED5353' to 'color':'#FFF'[/code]

Answer (score 0):

In your `mouseover` function you have

```
$('.afishaitem_up_left_active').css('color','#000');
```

And in your `mouseout` function you have the same

```
$('.afishaitem_up_left_active').css('color','#000');
```

If they are the same, the'd be no color change, change `#000` to any color you'd like.

```
$('.afishaitem_active').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css({'border':'solid 1px #ED5353','background-color':'#FFF','color':'#ED5353'});
            $('.afishaitem_up_left_active').css('color','#ED5353'); //changed color
        },
        function(){
            $(this).css({'border':'none','background-color':'#ED5353','color':'#FFF'});
            $('.afishaitem_up_left_active').css('color','#FFF'); //changed color
        }
    );​
```

[**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecm6T/4/)

Comment: not work change color in code:
$(this).css({'border':'solid 1px #ED5353','background-color':'#FFF','color':'#ED5353'}

$(this).css({'border':'none','background-color':'#ED5353','color':'#FFF'});

not work change 'color':'#ED5353' to 'color':'#FFF'

Answer (score 0):

Remove this class afishaitem_up_left_active from you table .. It should fix your issue..

```
<td class="afishaitem_up_left_active">'.$d.'</td>
```